# django memory leak during offline database insertion

Tags: django, memory-leaks

I have the following problem when inserting database data during an offline process (using management script):

```
from foo.models import bar

for i in links:
  bar.objects.create()
```

given links has a large number of entries. The process takes more and more memory during the loop.

Comment: Why not [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)?

Comment: I guess you have DEBUG = True in your settings. That could explain memory leaks

Comment: Thanks for the answers. @Ngenator, I have so much data that they don't fit into the memory at the same time. I however have time to read them off the disk and store them one by one.

Comment: You might want to look into using a [task queue](http://www.celeryproject.org/) then, or breaking it up into managable chunks so that you can use several bulk operations. I don't find it reasonable to say that a bulk operation can't be used due to the fact that there are too many items...

Comment: what is your actual code?

Comment: @Ngenator yes, it is certainly good to split the whole data into chunks. BUT, this does not actually answer the question of this thread. Since adding chunks would still cause the same memory issue, and only setting debug to false solved it.

Comment: I see, good to hear you got it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check `settings.DEBUG` is not `True`